# Permutations and Combination rearrangement

Tags: permutations

I approached this exam question the wrong way apparently, help please?

> Consider the word "mathematics". In how
>   many ways can you rearrange all the
>   letters so that the vowels are paired
>   and always apart?

Comment: How did you try it?  And what does "paired and always apart" mean?

Comment: Does "rearrange all the letters" imply there are no fixed points?

Answer (score 1):

Given there are four vowels, list all the ways to split them into pairs.  Now for each set of pairs think of each pair as a single character.  How many ways can you permute the resulting collection?  How many of those have the vowel pairs next to each other?

Comment: I did, I also divided out the repeating "a" as well as doing the same with the remaining letters of M,M,T,H,C,S. 1836 was not the answer

Comment: paired as in ae are a pair or ai BUT they cannot be near another pair. and Yes, no fixed points

Comment: The no fixed points may be the problem.  Frequently if you are asked how many ways can you rearrange abc the expected answer is 6, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

In the word "mathematics", the the vowels are {a, e, a, i} and the consonants are {m, t, h, n, t, c, s}.

We will put gaps between and around the consonants, like so:
_ m _ t _ h _ n _ t _ c _ s _

The number of ways the consonants can be permuted are: 7!/2! = 2,520 (we divide by 2! as the letter "t" is repeated)

Now, the four vowels need to be placed in 8 gaps. The first vowel can be placed in any of the 8 gaps. The second one, let's say, is forced to be with the first one to pair them up. The third one has 7 gaps. The fourth one is also forced to be with the third one. Therefore, there are 8 * 1 * 7 * 1 = 56 ways to permute the vowels. However, since "a" is repeated, we will divide by 2, arriving at 28 ways.

Combining the two results, there are: 28 * 2,520 = 70,560 ways to permute this.